# my android studio says no system image selected？

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I don't know why this happens? What should I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE 3D Printing. Your question does not appear to be about 3D printing. Are you sure that you have posted this question on the correct site? [Android enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would seem to be a better fit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about 3D printing.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden - Is it worth migrating to Android Enthusiasts?

Comment: @Greenonline Probably not. I'm not familiar with Andriod Enthusiasts, but this doesn't look like a good question: it's mainly an image without proper description, and I think there's not enough information in there for anyone to answer the question.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden - Agreed. If there was more *meat* to the question, then it may have been worth it, but as it stands...

Comment: Nope as a senior/lead android developer I have no clue what they are asking for. Maybe They meant to say they ar trying to create an emulator and they forgot to install the sdk.

Comment: Why is this still open?